# Change Google Search URL in Firefox's "Search Google for.." context menu

Tags: firefox

If you right click on a word in Firefox 13, a context menu shows

> search google for [that word]

Then if you click on it, it creates a new tab with a google search for that word. I'd like to change the default url for that search. To be specific, I want to change the current http search URL to https search URL.

Answer (score 2):

The context menu does *not* always show an entry for Google search, it shows an entry for the currently selected search engine. So you just have to change the search engine. A search plugin for encrypted Google search is available from e.g. http://mycroft.mozdev.org/google-search-plugins.html.

The search via context menu is *not* related to keyword.url, which is used when entering keywords in the address bar.

Comment: can't I change the URL for the searches from context menu by modifying something from `about:config`..? without any addon..?

Comment: No, you cannot modify your search engines through settings from about:config, but ... Yes, you can modify them without any add-on since you just have to add/create/edit a search plugin. A source for plugins is already mentioned in my previous answer. To modify plugins, edit the xml files in your searchplugins directory in your Firefox profile. See http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_what-information-is-stored-in-my-profile an/or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to add Google encrypted keyword search in Firefox.

- Type about:config in address bar.
- Search for **keyword.url**
- Edit the value and change the address to
  ***https://encrypted.google.com/***
- Install the addon [Add to Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-to-search-bar/)
- Open the Google HTTPs web search [page](https://encrypted.google.com/), right-click the search
  form and select Add to Search Bar.This opens a basic form where the name, keyword and  icon can be selected.Add engine to search bar.
- Restart the browser.

Now the keyword search will search with https search url.

Hope this helps

Comment: The question is about context menu searches, not keyword searches from the address bar.

Answer (score -1):

Actually

In about:config, the value for keyword.url ... just change it to: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=

The above method worked well, but the google engine needed the '/search?q=' after the google.com

Works like a charm.

Comment: The question is about context menu searches, not keyword searches from the address bar.